# Decode hex Data type

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-ce, mssql-jdbc

There is a SQL Server database for 1C.

[image]

I connected to this database and made a select request. And that’s what I got

[image]

what mean that **0x832B98DED0019A4A11E93804957CDAA6**? How I can decode this?

EDIT V1

that my select
[image]

Comment: That is binary data either `image` (depreciated) or `varbinary` - you need to know what is stored in there? We can't help with that...

Comment: could they be uniqueidentifiers stored in binary datatype column? `select cast(0x832B98DED0019A4A11E93804957CDAA6 as uniqueidentifier)`

Comment: i added my select. how i can modify it ?